# R Extract Substrings Using Regex Pattern

Tags: r, regex, shiny

I wish to extract substrings using R regex.

I'm able use regex to extract the data down to that seen here -

```
test_data <- '[1] "Fix 1 ID-2229\n"                                                                                                                                  
[2] "Fix 2.\n"                                                              
[3] "Fix 3 issue ID-2222"                       
[4] "ID-2088: Fix 4"           
[5] "ID-1984: Fix 5\n"                                                       
[6] "ID-1984: Fix 6"'
```

The reactive function is similar to -

```
pattern <- "id-[0-9]+""

changes <- reactive({
   this_env = get_environment(x_project, x_envs[x_envs$name == input$variable,]$id)

   this_commit = gl_get_commits(x_project, this_env$last_deployment.sha)

   commits = x_commits[is.na(x_commits$parent_ids1),]

   c_commits = commits[commits$committed_date > this_commit$created_at,]$message

   # At this stage c_commits looks similar to test_data
)}
```

Is it now possible to filter the c_commits using the regex pattern to extract a list of id's E.G. "ID-2088" or is there a better alterative ?

Comment: I guess I'd just be concerned on `'pattern <- 'id-[0-9]+' ` that might want to be 'ID-' to avoid upper/lower case issues. Otherwise following with interest in the 'reactive' case. Is c_commit essentially a log file?

Comment: When posting a question, please identify all libraries required.  In this case, whence `reactive` and all the functions included in that call ?

Comment: Anyway, if  `"ID-xxxx` is always followed with a colon,  just tell regex to "stop" the string extraction when a colon is found.   But if it isn't,  the search pattern might be  `ID-[0-9]{1,}` to catch numbers of any size.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the feedback.

The fix for this is

```
c_commits = commits[commits$committed_date > this_commit$created_at,]$message %>%
  str_extract_all("(?i)paa-[0-9]+") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  sort() %>%
  unique()
```

Comment: As @carl-witthoft suggests, mention of library(s) used is recommended to aid future readers, hence `stringr::str_extract_all`.